# div's size dynamic to text - clear both does not work

Tags: html, css

I would like that the div of the article (the white content, and the right grey column) will expand with the height of the text in the white.

I tried to add `clear:both` to #bodycont, however it doesn't help

How can I make it flexible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The solution was to add `display:table` and remove the height. Since allowed me to display the height based on the text.

Very simple!

Answer (score 1):

`clear: both;` is to be added AFTER using floats: placing it on `#bodycont` would be useful if your header had floats (I didn't check). Placing it on the parent will do nothing (though there're other methods where the selector begins with this parent, namely `parent:after { /* strange bunch of instructions working in IE8 and above */ }`, but that's not the parent itself)

Some general instructions:

- don't ever use the `height` property on columns or layout blocks.
  You don't know how much content will go there, on another similar page or in 1 year.
  You don't know if some visitors are [zooming text](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/F69.html) a lot or on a smartphone ([related](http://www.w3.org/TR/WCAG-TECHS/G179.html)).
  You can have a layout without a single use of `height` property: particular cases need `min-height` when graphical elements are to be displayed entirely (when there's a nice background of known height that shouldn't be cropped), general case is using methods that don't need the height of elements to display properly.
- add `clear: both` on the element that follows floating columns or on the sibling of an element that contain floats. In your case the footer.
- Floating an element means its content is removed from the (HTML) flow. It doesn't "count" anymore for determining the height of a parent, it's not really there. Thus, an element that only contain floats have an height of ... 0. Everything was removed from the flow, no height. That'as annoying if you had a background on this parent as it won't display anymore... but you still want that background to have the same height as the tallest of the floating children. A (not so) modern clearfix is described by Thierry Koblentz here: http://www.yuiblog.com/blog/2010/09/27/clearfix-reloaded-overflowhidden-demystified/ (the `:before` part is only there for consistent collapsing margins, you only need the `:after` along with the parent, err betweeen the parent and the next element, that's where `:after` is)

Comment: Hi! I tried to add clear: both to the footer but it didn't help. I also tried the .clearfix:after {
    content: ".";
    display: block;
    height: 0;
    clear: both;
    visibility: hidden;
} but it didn't work

Comment: `.leftcolumntextimages` has floats and should've a clearfix like `.leftcolumntextimages:after`. But that won't show as long as the different columns and parent have fixed heights. Also, as you've columns into a column, this same white column should be floating along the grey right column (and then their parent should also have a clearfix). I can't figure if it should be `float: right` or `left` because of hebrew and `dir="rtl"` though, I'm not accustomed :)